# Skipping lost segments in Exoplayer Android

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I have a live DASH stream playing through Exoplayer. Due to certain issues with signal or reception I might loose certain segments while live streaming. I have also included a custom error policy to retry 3 times for the lost segment. So currently, if segments are lost, exoplayer retries for 3 times and stops throwing 404 or 410 Source error.
Instead of exoplayer throwing error and stopping, I want it to skip that segment and ask for next segment. How can this be achieved with exoplayer?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the DASH chunk size is something around 4 seconds. 
So if we take that assumption in consideration when an error occur (and it is not a 403 error code) you can try this line:

```
player.seekTo(player.getCurrentPosition() + 4000)
```

Comment: the segment size depends on the packager output and hardcoding seek position will result in other errors as in when the play position is very close to the live-edge.

Answer (score 0):

I might have some solution for you, but i have not tested it for various use-cases.

override the onLoadError function within ChunkSampleStream to return success, even when the segment fails. Exoplayer will consider that as success and move to next chunk. When the play position reaches that point it considers it as a discontuinity and pauses for the duration of the segment and then continues playback.

```
public LoadErrorAction onLoadError(
  Chunk loadable,
  long elapsedRealtimeMs,
  long loadDurationMs,
  IOException error,
  int errorCount) {

if(errorCount > 3 // you can put any retry limit here ){


  chunkSource.onChunkLoadCompleted(loadable);
  eventDispatcher.loadCompleted(
      loadable.dataSpec,
      loadable.getUri(),
      loadable.getResponseHeaders(),
      loadable.type,
      primaryTrackType,
      loadable.trackFormat,
      loadable.trackSelectionReason,
      loadable.trackSelectionData,
      loadable.startTimeUs,
      loadable.endTimeUs,
      elapsedRealtimeMs,
      loadDurationMs,
      loadable.bytesLoaded());
  callback.onContinueLoadingRequested(this);
  LoadErrorAction loadErrorAction = null;
  loadErrorAction = Loader.DONT_RETRY;
  return loadErrorAction;
}else{ 
  the rest of the function should be pasted here
}
```

hope it helps
even i was stuck at this problem for couple of hours